# Jquery autocomplete not displaying results, custom renderItem

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement a custom renderItem method and and not getting any autocomplete results. I want to include both the label and value in the list and align the label to the right. Here's what I have tried so far.

**ajax.js**

```
function autoCompleteResults(str) {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'includes/autocomplete.php?q=' + str,
       data: '{}',
       dataType: 'json',
       success: function(data) {
           console.log(data);
           $('#search-input').autocomplete({
              source: data,
              minLength: 2,
              delay: 500
           }).data('ui-autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
               return $('<li></li>').data('item.ui-autocomplete', item)
                       .append('<a>' + item.value + '<span class="ac-label">' + item.label + '</span></a>')
                       .appendTo(ul);
           };
       }
    });
}
```

**html:**

```
<div class="search">
    <form method="get" action="index.php">
        <label class="search-label">Enter search value:</label>
        <input id="search-input" class="search-input" type="text" name="searchvalue" onkeyup="autoCompleteResults(this.value);" autocomplete="off">
        <button class="search-input-btn" type="submit" name="search" value="1">Search</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

**php:**

```
$key = $_SESSION['key'];
$q = $_GET['q'];
$response = sp_sproc_wrapper($q, $key);

$response_str = array();
foreach ($response as $key => $value) {
    $response_str[] = array(
        'value' => $value['number'],
        'label' => $value['attribute'],
    );
}

echo json_encode($response_str);
```

Comment: you do have `session_start();` ?

Comment: @rtfm yes, in index as well as the autocomplete script.

Comment: no idea what `sp_sproc_wrapper` is but how about dumping the results of `$response` to see if the query worked

Comment: sure, sorry about that.  'autocomplete.php?q=rd' and got back [{"value":"RD","label":"Part #"},{"value":"RD","label":"Part #"},{"value":"RD","label":"Part #"},{"value":"RD","label":"Part #"},{"value":"RD","label":"Part #"}]